# Getting asynchronously loading external HTML data with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, web-scraping

If i run `$("a[data-control-name='identity_profile_photo']").attr('href')` on my Linkedin homepage, it prints well. Shows me my profile url. However, if I run the code below returns undefined. How can i make the code below work and show me my profile url?

```
$(document).ready(function getLinkedinID(){
    $.ajax({
        url:'https://www.linkedin.com/feed/',
        type:'get',
        success: function(data){
            $html = data;
            $data = $("a[data-control-name='identity_profile_photo']", $html).attr('href');
            console.log($data);
            }
    });
});
```

Comment: I think This request will not be trigger else if you have allow access origin to access linked-in. .., Any way, If you console.log(data) what is will be print?

Comment: @AneesHikmatAbuHmiad  I have allow access. I am working on my browser. I think there is no cross domain issue. If it was worked, it would printed /in/my-name-myid

Comment: Nice mate, if you console.log(data); is print any thing or its come empty?

Comment: @AneesHikmatAbuHmiad prints `undefined`

Comment: Can you please try this: setTimeout(function(){ console.log(data); }, 5000); inside success .... To make sure response is come ...

Comment: @AneesHikmatAbuHmiad it prints whole html.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182823/discussion-between-tahtakafa-and-anees-hikmat-abu-hmiad).

Comment: Hay mate, are you execute code in discussion?

Comment: @AneesHikmatAbuHmiad Nope. I couldn't.